# how to get mysql monitoring value from active cheks

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new at Zabbix and English.
I want to get Zabbix MySQL monitoring value from server which cannot connect from zabbix server.
So I want to get value from active check zabbix agent to zabbix server.
Mysql monitoring function is only passive check?
Please let me know how to do this.

Comment: import the template and turn it into active https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZBX/repos/zabbix/browse/templates/db/mysql_agent?at=refs%2Fheads%2Frelease%2F5.0

Comment: I don't get it. Import MySQL by Zabbix agent or MySQL by Zabbix agent2 and turn it into active check mode? Do you know Is there any website which written how to do that.

Comment: it's just one click to change from "zabbix agent" to "zabbix agent (active)" in the Zabbix GUI